# CSS: select last div with specific class

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors, primeng

```
<ul>
  <li class="class1">
    <div class="custom">text1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div class="custom">text2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div class="custom">text3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div>text4</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div>text5</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I select last `div` with `class="custom"`? I have to add `border-bottom` to `div` with text3. I tried:

```
.class1 .custom:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

...But then `border-bottom` is added to all `div`'s with `class="custom"`.
I need CSS solution only, no JS. Also there could be any amount of `<li>` so I can't use `:nth-child()`.

Update:
This layout is generated from Prime NG component `<p-autocomplete>`
The code is:

```
<p-autocomplete ....>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    <div [ngClass]="{'custom'}: item.isCustom">
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-autocomplete>
```

Comment: @04FS as the custom divs are not siblings, that is not a duplicate.

Comment: There is currently no way to do this with css alone, you'll probably need to use your server side language to do it - (I guess that's what is applying the custom class)

Comment: What is applying the custom class?

Comment: Ah probably one for the angular gurus then - In you js code, I would apply an extra class to the last item that isCustom (or add a property so that you could apply it in your ngClass statement)

Comment: @Pete, Ok then. The main question was if it's possible to do with CSS only. So I will  try to do it with js.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments saying that a pure-CSS solution is not existing, because it is not possible to aggregate special selectors like `:last-of-type` as for example `(.class1 .custom):last-of-type` (not working).

What i propose is a simple JQuery solution:

```js
$(".class1 .custom").last().parents(".class1").addClass("custom2");
```

```css
.custom2{
   border-bottom: 1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="class1">
    <div class="custom">text1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div class="custom">text2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div class="custom">text3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div>text4</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div>text5</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proud of this, but it's CSS only and it works.

```css
.class1 .custom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.class1 .custom::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="class1">
    <div class="custom">text1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div class="custom">text2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div class="custom">text3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div>text4</div>
  </li>
  <li class="class1">
    <div>text5</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```